# Populate treeview with dynamic subnodes

Tags: c#, treeview

I have table with two columns:

```
+-------------+------------+  
| Level       | Desc       |  
+-------------+------------+  
| 1           | a          |  
+-------------+------------+    
| 2           | b          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 2           | c          | 
+-------------+------------+    
| 1           | d          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 2           | e          | 
+-------------+------------+    
| 2           | f          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 3           | g          | 
+-------------+------------+    
| 1           | h          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 1           | i          | 
+-------------+------------+ 
| 2           | j          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 2           | k          | 
+-------------+------------+
```

And I need to create display of this data in treeview according to Level column and it 
should be like:

```
- 1 a
   -- 2 b
   -- 2 c
 -1 d
   -- 2 e
   -- 2 f
      -- 3 g
 -1 h
 -1 i 
   -- 2 j 
   -- 2 k
```

So, level columns represents the node. Level 1 is the main node, level 2 is subnode of level 1, level 3 is subnode of level 2, level 4 is subnode of 3...
I know how to populate treeview when  there is fixed numbers of nodes and subnodes but in this case don't have idea how to populate where 1 node consist 3, 4 or more subnodes.

Comment: how do you hold this table ?

Comment: DataTable with two columns (int, string)

Comment: I have corrected a little bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it will help you, i tried your example and it worked successfully

```
    private void PopulateTreeView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Level");
        table.Columns.Add("Data");

        table.Rows.Add(1, "a");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "b");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "c");
        table.Rows.Add(1, "d");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "e");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "f");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "g");
        table.Rows.Add(4, "z");
        table.Rows.Add(5, "x");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "h");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "i");
        table.Rows.Add(1, "j");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "k"); 

        TreeNode lastNode = new TreeNode();    

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode((string)table.Rows[i]["Data"]);                

            if (i == 0)
                treeView.Nodes.Add(newNode);
            else
            {
                int currentLevel = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["Level"]);
                int lastLevel = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i-1]["Level"]);

                if (currentLevel < lastLevel)
                {
                    if (currentLevel == 1)
                        treeView.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                    else
                    {
                        TreeNode currentNode = lastNode.Parent;

                        for (int j = 0; j < lastLevel - currentLevel; j++)
                            currentNode = currentNode.Parent;

                        currentNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                    }
                }
                else if (currentLevel == lastLevel)
                {
                     if (lastLevel == 1)
                        treeView.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                     else
                        lastNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(newNode);                                    
                }
                else
                {
                    lastNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                }
            }

            lastNode = newNode;
        }           
    }
```

[image]